# Show that $\int_{[-1, 1]} f d sgn = 2 f(0).$ (Analysis 1 by Tao)

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Exercise 11.8.5. Let $sgn : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the signum function; $sgn(x) = 1$ when $x >0$, $=0$ when $x=0$, and $=-1$ when $x<0$. Let $f : [-1, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Show that $f $is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable with respect to $sgn$, and that 
$$\int_{[-1, 1]} f d sgn = 2 f(0).$$ 
(Hint: for every $\epsilon >0$, find piecewise constant functions majorizing and minorizing $f$ whose Riemann-Stieltjes integral is $\epsilon$-close to $2f(0)$. )

Attept: Since $f$ is continuous on a closed interval, it is uniformly continuous. From the previous exercise, we know that $f$ is Riemann-Stieltjes integral. For the next part, since $f$ is bounded, $f([-1, 1]) \subset [-M, M]$ for some $M \in \mathbb{R}^+$. Therefore, let $h(x) = -M$ and $g(x) = M$ for all $x$. Then, $h$ and $g$ minorizes and majorizes $f$, but I don't think that this helps to show $f$ is $\epsilon$-close to $2f(0)$.

I appreciate if you give some help.

Comment: I suggest ignoring all the theorems and working directly with the definition of the Riemann-Stieltjes integral.

Comment: I don't know how to solve it but the derivative of the [sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function#Properties) function is twice the delta dirac $\int_{[-1, 1]} f d sgn = \int_{[-1, 1]} f(2\delta(x))dx=2 f(0)$ so maybe that could help give some idea about how to proceed to give a rigorous proof